# Apply google password change to android

Tags: google-account, password

I've recently changed my google account password on my PC. My phone/android then started prompting me for my google password but I've been having trouble in that the password isn't working, it then said something about needing to log in from a browser instead which also had trouble. The prompt now seems to have disappeared so I've rebooted but still no prompt yet.

It's obvious android detected the password change but now something has gone wrong. Is there a way I can manually fix this? I've briefly seen something about removing the account but that warns that all messages, contacts etc will be removed which doesn't quite seem like the best way to go about it...

Comment: Is everything working? If so, it took the password change successfully even though it didn't tell you what you expected. If it's not working, yes delete and add Google Acct, it will delete items specific to your Google account, most of which are stored server side anyway, don't let the warning scare you too much, it won't erase text messages or anything like that.

Comment: It seems to be, I'm still logged in to everything, play store, gmail, etc. The password prompt was weird and seemed like it wasn't working, perhaps it still did take the change, would there be someway of confirming?

Comment: Sync something... make a change to contact or send/recieve an email via Gmail, if it works then the password change took. Pretty simple actually.

Comment: Sending mail from gmail works ok. Under my accounts it's says Sync disabled and I think it's because I set one or two apps to not sync automatically at some point but it looks as though sync has been disabled completely. How do I enable sync again and how do I disable individual apps from syncing?