# I changed my Google account password on my PC. How do I make the change on my phone and tablets?

Tags: google-account, password

I changed my Google account password on my PC. That went fine. But how do I make the change on my phone and tablets? I don't want the phone or Google apps on the phone to suddenly ask me for the password when I'm out doing something. I want to change it pro-actively.  But I have not found any way to re-log-in to my Google account on the phone.

Phone is a Samsung Galaxy running Android version 7.0 (I know, I know. New phone in the near future).

Prior Research: A similar (unanswered) question has been asked here 5 years ago [Apply google password change to android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160244/apply-google-password-change-to-android) but the difference is that I am not experiencing the difficulties that poster was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google usually does not use passwords for authentication on Android. Only for the initial account set-up you have to enter username and password which is then sent to the Google authentication server but not stored on your phone.

If username and password were correct the authentication server sends back an long term oAuth authentication token (looks like a long string of random characters - usually 50 character or longer) which used for authentication and updated periodically by the server (about every month).

Therefore changing the password has no effect on your Android device. If you want to logout devices from your Google account, Google provides a web page where you cans see all active devices and where you can log out each device if want:
http://google.com/devices